# JDK8: unable to parse LocalTime

Tags: java, java-8, date-parsing

I managed to parse a `String` to a `LocalDate` object:

```
DateTimeFormatter f1=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yyyy");
LocalDate d=LocalDate.parse("26 08 1984",f1);
System.out.println(d); //prints "1984-08-26"
```

But I cannot do the same with `LocalTime`. This piece of code:

```
DateTimeFormatter f2=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh mm");
LocalTime t=LocalTime.parse("11 08",f2); //exception here
System.out.println(t);
```

Throws a `DateTimeParseException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11 08' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=8, HourOfAmPm=11},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.mui.cert.Main.<init>(Main.java:21)
    at com.mui.cert.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=8, HourOfAmPm=11},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalTime$$Lambda$15/1854731462.queryFrom(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use a specific format, according to [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-):

> The string must represent a valid time and is parsed using [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME).

```
hh mm
```

for 24h must be

```
HH mm
```

or for 12h

```
kk mm
```

The handled formats must have this conditions:

- Two digits for the hour-of-day. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
- A colon
- Two digits for the minute-of-hour. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
- If the second-of-minute is not available then the format is complete.
- A colon
- Two digits for the second-of-minute. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
- If the nano-of-second is zero or not available then the format is complete.
- A decimal point
- One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.

Comment: Can you link the resource please?

Comment: That's interesting, I thougth I could mess indefinitely with the order of the elements...

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("kk mm")`; for 12 hour clock or `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH mm")` for 24 hour clock

If you want to parse time with `hh` you must combine it wih `a` where you define AM or PM:

```
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh mm a");
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse("11 08 AM", f2);
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case `Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor` means it cannot determine the how far through the day the given string represents i.e. there is not enough information to construct a `LocalTime`. Behind the scenes, the code looks something like this expanded Java 8 version (which gives a similar error):

```
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh mm");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = f2.parse("11 08");
LocalTime t = temporalAccessor.query(LocalTime::from);
System.out.println(t);
```

The [`LocalTime::from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-) documentation says

> The conversion uses the TemporalQueries.localTime() query, which
>   relies on extracting the NANO_OF_DAY field.

Your error is telling you that the `TemporalAccessor` only has two fields, neither of which is a `NANO_OF_DAY` field. The minimum allowable patterns for retrieving a `LocalTime` using a `DateTimeFormatter` are:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ha");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Ka");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ah");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("aK");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("k");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H");
```

Your pattern must contain at least one of those strings to get a `NANO_OF_DAY` field in the internal `TemporalAccessor` from which a `LocalTime` can be constructed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capital HH in the pattern

```
DateTimeFormatter f2=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH mm");
```

or do this, for `clock-hour-of-am-pm` you need to specify it.

This should also work

```
DateTimeFormatter f2=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh mm a");
LocalTime t=LocalTime.parse("11 08 AM",f2); //exception here
```

Comment: it works... but why? `h -> clock-hour-of-am-pm` should work too!

Comment: I think that `am-pm` part is important - it can refer to two distinct LocalTimes (one for am and one for pm)