# Java LocalTime Parse Exception

Tags: java, localtime

I had a piece of code that worked just fine and now somehow doesn't work.

I am reading in a csv file and get an error when reading in a time field of the format `4:38`.

My code that throws the exception is:

```
LocalTime.parse("4:38", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))
```

I also tried `"H:mm"` or `"H:m"` for the pattern but it throws the same exception: `Text '4:38' could not be parsed at index 0`. Any idea to why it throws an exception at the hour number?

I am using Java 8.

Comment: use the value of `"04:38"`

Comment: That means I got to edit the entire csv file. Isn't there another way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754259/jdk8-unable-to-parse-localtime

Comment: I would try to correct the csv builder if possible. What is that format of time ... H:MM. Where is it comming from ?

Comment: "H:mm" or "H:m" should work correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pattern needs one single "H" and one single "m".

```
LocalTime.parse("4:38", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m"));
```

It works fine for 4:38 and 14:38.

[Official Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): See "Patterns for Formatting and Parsing"

Comment: That is what I also had thought. Turns out, I forgot that I am parsings two identical values, and the exception was being thrown by the duplicate value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"H:mm" is working fine for me.[image][image]